# How to change the minicart icon in theme header?

Tags: magento2

How do I change the mini cart icon to my own SVG in the theme header?
I guess CSS isn't the best practice so thinking of other options.

is it this one in view.xml?

```
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set icon of minicart by css. Here i do paste code of one of my project.

```
.minicart {
    background: url(../images/minicart.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

so your minicart image must be under below path.

```
app/code/design/frontend/<theme_vendor>/<theme_package>/web/images/<minicart.png>
```

And you need to include css for the same theme as below.

```
app/code/design/frontend/<theme_vendor>/<theme_package>/web/css/<style.css>
```

Below code is just to set product thumbnail image height and width in minicart popup

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
        <width>75</width>
        <height>75</height>
    </image>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

::First let me clear that you can't edit magento core themes directly from /app/design/magento!!!::

::If you want to change it your self then, you've to create your own one and make changes as required!!::

::Now let's go to the point!::

::first => Create custom.css file at /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/::

::second => create default.xml file at
/app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/::

::Now put the file contents like below::

::CSS::

::

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{

content:url('../images/minicart.jpg')!important;

zoom:1.5%;}
```

::

::XML::

```
<head>
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

//make sure to copy the default structure for xml file.

//I have not pasted that here because i am a noob to stackexchange!!

:::Last Step :::

move your new minicart image to the
/app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/images/minicart.img extension

::Finally run below commands::

::Make sure to remove /pub/static/frontend::

::bin/magento setup:upgrade::

::bin/magento setup:di:compile::

::bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f::

::bin/magento indexer:reindex::

::bin/magento cache:flush::

::chmod -R 777 ../magento root directory name::

::Thank You::